# Multi language support for website

Tags: php, multilingual

While trying to modify eyeos install index page to support multi language using gettext method, i was unable to resolve an issue with the index page.

ISSUE:

The index page has 4 steps

It is possible to change the front page to the language we choose

but when i try to click next step it shows the default language rather than the choosen one

and also report an error as **"Undefined index: submit in /var/www/html/install/index.php on line 78"**

How can i resolve it...

the index.php file is

> 

```
      <?php
        ob_start();
            if(!isset($_GET['step'])) 
            {
            $step = 'introduction';
           }  
           else 
           {
            $step = basename($_GET['step']);
           }
           require_once('steps/'.$step.'.php');
         echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
           ?>
             <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css"/>
     <title>eyeOS 2 installation</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="language">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="change language"/>
</form>

        <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <div id="topbar" class="topbar">
                <img src="logo-eyeos.png" id="logo" class="logo" />
                <div id="logotext" class="logotext">
                    <? echo toptext(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
                <ul class="sidelist">
                    <?php

                        if ($_POST['submit'])
                        {
                            bindtextdomain('messages', './');
                            textdomain('messages');

                            $lang=$_POST['language'];

                            if ($lang)
                            {

                                switch ($lang) 
                                {
                                    case 'es':
                                        putenv('LC_ALL=es_ES'); 
                                        setlocale(LC_ALL,'es_ES');
                                        break;
                                    case 'en':
                                    default:
                                        setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_GB');
                                        break;
                                }
                            }               


                        if($step == 'introduction') {
                            echo _('<li class="selected">Introduction</li>');
                        } else {
                            echo _('<li>Introduction</li>');
                        }

                        if($step == 'requirements') {
                            echo _('<li class="selected">Requirements</li>');
                        } else {
                            echo _('<li>Requirements</li>');
                        }
                        if($step == 'configuration') {
                            echo _('<li class="selected">Configuration</li>');
                        } else {
                            echo _('<li>Configuration</li>');
                        }

                        if($step == 'end') {
                            echo _('<li class="selected">End</li>');
                        } else {
                            echo _('<li>End</li>');
                        }
                        }  

                    ?>
                </ul>
            </span>
            <span id="content" class="content">
                  <?php getContent(); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
</body>
```

and i edited some line in messages.po file

Lines are

1."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"

2.

## : index.php:81

msgid "Introduction"
msgstr "Introducción"

## : index.php:83

msgid "

Introduction

"
msgstr "

Introducción

"

3.

## : index.php:87

msgid "Requirements"
msgstr "Requisitos"

## : index.php:89

msgid "

Requirements

"
msgstr "

Requisitos

"

4.

## : index.php:92

msgid "Configuration"
msgstr "Configuración"

## : index.php:94

msgid "

Configuration

"
msgstr "

Configuración

"

5.

## : index.php:98

msgid "End"
msgstr "Final"

## : index.php:100

msgid "

End

"
msgstr "

Final

"

2.#: index.php:81
msgid "Introduction"
msgstr "Introducción"

## : index.php:83

msgid "

Introduction

"
msgstr "

Introducción

"

Comment: you should work on improving your acceptance of answers if they are fit for purpose ... or asking newer questions...if they aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error you report, `and also report an error as "Undefined index: submit in /var/www/html/install/index.php on line 78"`, change:

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

2nd issue:

I would add some debugging to your code to see what the result of `$_POST['language']` is.  Maybe you aren't catching the language properly in your `switch`

Comment: switch is working fine..the error msg got resolved.. but the problem still persists

ie:I canot transfer the side menu to the selected language when click next

Comment: Is there any way to hold the selected language as primery